# Listbox and ObservableCollection, repopulating

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, observablecollection

I have two listboxes, items sources for both listboxes are ObservableCollections of type "Element", depending upon selected Element in the listbox1, i want to show it's subElements in listbox2

here is part of code:

```
ObservableCollection< Element> source1 = new ObservableCollection< Element>();
ObservableCollection< Element> source2 = new ObservableCollection< Element>();

Listbox2.ItemsSource = source2; 

public class Element 
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection< Element> subElements { get; set; }
 }


private void Listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var items = ((Element)sender).subElements;
     source2 = items;
     // i tried many variants, it never works to (re)populate Listbox2
 }
```

even if i clear all of the elements from source2 before trying to fill it with new elements, it won't work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace `source2` with another instance of `ObservableCollection`, because binding reference is lost. You should use properties instead of fields or just add all elements to the collection instead of replacing the reference:

```
private void Listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var items = ((Element)sender).subElements;
     source.Clear();
     foreach(var i in items)
          source2.Add(i);
 }
```

Comment: hey, thanks for advice, but it still doesn't seem to work ... should this code work? am i doing something else wrong? thanks again!